# How to create Training data for Text classification on 4 categories

Tags: text, machine-learning, classification, naivebayes

My machine learning goal is to search for potential risks (will cost more money) and opportunities (will save money) from a Project Requirements document.

My idea is to classify sentences from the data into one of these categories: Risk, Opportunity and Irrelevant (no risk, no opportunity, default categorie).

I will use a multinomial Bayes classifier for this with tf-dif.

Now I need to have data for my training set and test set. The way I will do this is label every sentence from requirement documents with 1 of the 3 categories. Is this a good approach?

Or should I only label sentences which are obviously a risk/opportunity/irrelevant?

Also, is the Irrelevant categorie a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the three-class approach is a good one. This is similar to sentiment analysis, where you typically have positive, negative and neutral documents (or sentences). The neutral comprises the vast majority of the instances, so your classification problem will be unbalanced. That is not necessarily an issue, but for difficult problems like this one, a naive bayes classifier might simply classify everything in the neutral/irrelevant bucket since the prior for neutral will be quite high.

- your sampling (labeling) should be representative of the reality. Don't try to create a dataset of 1000 risk, 1000 opportunity, 1000 irrelevant. Instead, take a sample of say 10000 requirements, and assign the proper label to each, even if it means having much more 'Irrelevant' than 'Risk' for instance.
- text classification models require many instances, since the search space is vast. I wonder if you have considered the fact that to get reliable results (say over 90%), you may need to manually label thousands of instances.
- and even if you have thousands of training instances, your problem looks particularly difficult, unless there are some obvious keywords to trigger 'risk' or 'opportunity' that I don't understand. Ask yourself: would this be easy for a human to judge? If you asked 3 judges to classify your requirements, would they all come up with the same answer? If not, then it might be 10s of thousands of training documents that you will need, and the classification accuracy may still be disappointing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me. I do realise I will have to go through many documents and label every sentence. Initially I thought I needed the same amount of training samples for every categorie, but as you say this is not the case. Then I will simply go through every document and label every sentence with 1 of the 3 categories, I will end up with much more Irrelevant samples indeed.

Avout 70 percent accuracy wouldn't be bad.. Do you think this is possible with about 5000 sentences labeled?

Comment: My feeling is that I would find challenging identifying risks and opportunities from requirements in a consistent way, let alone for a text classifier. That said, maybe your case is different from my experience and maybe opportunities and risks in your situation is simply a short set of technologies with related keywords (example: machine learning, NLP = opportunities, SOC 2 compliance = risk). Again, to learn from 5000 examples, the task needs to be very easy for a human

Comment: Thanks. The task is not very simple for a human, however there are keywords such as 'responsible' that occur a lot of times in risk-sentences. How do I tell the program that if such words occur, a particular label is much more likely?

Comment: I would try first without adding manually created rules like that. One of the benefit of machine learning is that you don't have to maintain sets of manual rules that are hard to maintain, combine, etc. But if you really need to, you can multiply the resulting class probabilities of your classifier by your manually created probabilities.