# Text classification/Machine learning: do I also need a 'Default' categorie?

Tags: text, machine-learning, classification, naivebayes

For my assignment I need to make a Machine Learning program which does the following:

As input the program gets a building plan (written in text in PDF) for a project, mainly bridges and sluices. The machine learning program takes every sentence in that PDF as a sample (the words in that sentence are the features), and needs to classify every sample/sentence in one of the following categories: Hardware related and Software related. (I use the Naive Bayes algorithm in combination with TF-DIF. )

However, as you can imagine, there are also a lot of irrelevant sentences which are neither hardware nor software related. Do I need to make a seperate categorie 'Default/Irrelevant', so that I have three categories in total? Or is it better to keep only the two categories, and classify them based on their probability? For example; a sentence is classified as hardware at 0.6, then I ignore it. But if the outcome is 0.8 or higher, then I classify it as hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use irrelevant sentences in your training set, I will explain the reason with one example:

If you have a three class classification problem you can obtain this output:
     Irrelevant 95%
     Hardware    4%
     Software    1%

The possibility of being Harware is 4 times the posibility of being Software. But you obviously will choose Irrelevant.

If you use a two class dataset you will obtain this output:
     Hardware   80%
     Software   20%

The posibility of being Hardware is again 4 times the posibility of being Software, but both percentages must sum 100% because the classifier thinks that both posibilities are the whole universum.

You have two different options:

1 - A 3 class classification problem (Hardware, Software, Irrelevant)

2 - Two classifiers with 2 class classification problem:

Classifier 1 -> Positive class Hardware, Negative class: Software + Irrelevant

Classifier 2 -> Positive class Software, Negative clas: Hardware + Irrelevant

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I will make an extra categorie which covers the irrelevant sentences.

One more question. When I'm classifying sentences, sometimes I really doubt whether it should be classified as hardware or as irrelevant, but then I'm usually slightly leaning towards Irrelevant. Should I cover these kind of sentences in the training set? Or shouldn't I use these questionable sentences in the training set?

Comment: You are wellcome. The basic idea is that the dataset must contain the same proportion of HW, SW and Irrelevant sentences that you will have in the future to obtain good probabilities. About the sentences that you are not sure about the category, there are some algorihms that can handle uncertainty, but they are more complex to work with. In my opinion, if you don't mind the future classification of that kind of sentences, remove them from the training set, if you preffer to classify them as irrelevant, include them in the training set using the label irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I will not put those kind of sentences in the training set.
I've seen others say that you don't need to try to get the same amount of training samples for every category. They say that it's just fine if the spread is the same as the real data.  I was happy to hear that as the SW category is in the far minority (about 70 percent irrelevant, 25 percent hardware and 5 percent software). So, do I really need to try to get the same amount of samples for every categorie? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39444786/how-to-create-training-data-for-text-classification-on-4-categories

Comment: Also, the recall for HW/SW it much more important than the precision. As I have far more sentences which are irrelevant, I really want that HW/SW sentences to be predicted correctly. It doesn't really matter if some irrelevant sentences are classified as HW/SW.

Answer (score 0):

Each method would work depending on how much training data you will use. Currently I am working on a large project which, in essence, does a similar task with text, sentance by sentence, although I am using 7 categories. I have used 7 labels, so no 'irrelevant' bucket'. I use a thresh hold when presenting the findings, so anything above 0.75 certainty rating, this works fine. The problem with using an 'irrelevant' bucket is you have to train it what is 'irrelevant', which could be a massive diverse data set. So go with your probability option.